# There are no commands defined in the "scout" namespace. laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have installed laravel scout on my project recently and when i was trying to publish the config files i used this command :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"
```

but it gaves this error :

```
  INFO  No publishable resources for tag [].
```

i have copied the file manaully but now when i try to run the commands for it like below :

```
php artisan scout:flush
```

it tells me that this command doesnt exists while it does i have checked that

```
   ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "scout" namespace.
```

[image]

Comment: To install scout you ran `composer require laravel/scout` ? Normally it should be followed automatically by a run of `php artisan package:discover`. Did it happen?

Comment: Did you run `composer dump` after package installation?